# Listener for new AdminEvents WTelegramClient

Tags: c#, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

There is a task that requires me to process every person who joins/leaves the telegram channel. I found the WTelegramClient library. How can I use it to implement a handler for this kind of action?
I need to process the records that are kept here:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2fNb.jpg)

I tried working with https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/Examples/Program_ListenUpdates.cs?ts=4#L23, but it doesn't know how to handle this kind of message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately [`ChannelAdminLogEvent`](https://core.telegram.org/api/recent-actions) are not pushed by Telegram as updates.

The only solution is to poll for them with [`Channels_GetAdminLog`](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.getAdminLog)

Comment: Hmm. Is there any way to get Telegram to push me information about who is leaving the channel? I'm looking at the telegram bot API now, there's a way to process incoming requests to join the channel and so you can implement a count of subscribers.

Comment: Not for channels. Bot API relies on a subset of Client API so you can't learn more using Bot API.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem, a simpler solution was needed. I needed to enable receiving "chat_member". This tells you when someone joins or leaves the channel. Again, works for both chats and channels.

If you still need to get information from the 'Recent actions' page, there's only one option - telegram user api.

Comment: You're right! In WTelegramClient you would receive an UpdateChannelParticipant for people joining/leaving a channel.

I thought this would not be the case for channels. Maybe it does not happen for big channels.

Comment: In C# Telegram.Bot is UpdateType.ChatMember.